# what does the stackoverflow api filter parameter fromdate mean?

Tags: api

I want to collect user data from api.stackexchange.com/docs/users/.But I don't know what does the filter parameters fromdate mean.And the data format in returned data is like '1453274975',I don't know it stands for when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fromdate` parameter allows you to filter users by their account creation date, to retrieve those created after the date you specify.

The date format used by the StackOverflow API is in [unix epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), as explained [in their doc](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates).